# Two Selects with same data

Tags: php, html, select

I want to select a versus of teams, I have made two selects and show the teams from database: what I have did is that :

```
   <p>  
    <label>Teams</label>
    <select id="team1" name="team1">
      <option disabled selected value>Team 1</option>
      <?php

        while ($team = $db->fetch_array($teams))
        {
            echo renderTeamsSelect($team);
        }
        $db->free_result($teams);

      ?>
    </select>
    VS
    <select id="team2" name="team2">
      <option disabled selected value>Team 2</option>
      <?php

        while ($team = $db->fetch_array($teams))
        {
            echo renderTeamsSelect($team);
        }
        $db->free_result($teams);

      ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Note that $team is :

```
$teams = $db->query('SELECT * FROM teams');
```

and my function renderTeamSelect is :

```
function renderTeamsSelect($team)
{
return '<option value="' . $team['id'] . '">' . $team['name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Once I see the result in html , team 2 is not showing anything in options.

I included a screenshot

[image: Error]

I can't understand why Select one is showing results and select 2 no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A far better approach:-

```
<?php

$teams = $db->query('SELECT * FROM teams');
$final_data = '';
 while ($team = $db->fetch_array($teams))
{
    $final_data .=  renderTeamsSelect($team);
}
function renderTeamsSelect($team)
{
return '<option value="' . $team['id'] . '">' . $team['name'] . '</option>';
}

?>

<p>  
    <label>Teams</label>
    <select id="team1" name="team1">
      <option disabled selected value>Team 1</option>
      <?php  echo $final_data ;?>
    </select>
    VS
    <select id="team2" name="team2">
      <option disabled selected value>Team 2</option>
        <?php  echo $final_data ;?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

could be you are using

```
 $db->free_result($teams);
```

In this way you free the result

try perform this only at the end  of you page  (omit the first)

Comment: why not call function only one time and store result in one variable and use at both places?

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge . :)